# Como puedo concatenar correctamente una variable a esta expresión regular?

Tags: javascript

quiero agregar correctamente una variable a una expresión regular como la que expreso a continuación:

```
let galleta_nom = "2023BURA07C03P07"; 
let galletaValor = document.cookie.replace(/(?: 
(?:^|.*;\s*)/\+galleta_nom+\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/,"$1",);

alert(galletaValor)
```

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta para explicar qué intenta hacer tu expresión regular?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el constructor de regex y [String literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) para añadir una variable a la expresión regular:

```js
const variable = 'inter'

const regex = new RegExp(`^[\\d\\w]{5}_${variable}_[\\d\\w]{5}$`, 'gim');

console.log(regex.test('holas_inter_holas'))
console.log(regex)
```

Nótese que necesito usar doble backslash para que me tome las expresiones \w y \d, de lo contrario la expresión regular no hara 'match'.
Puedes pasar la expresión regular construida al método *replace* para utilizarla como quieras.

Por cierto parece que tu regex tiene errores, tal como esta.

Comment: Hola alanfcm, si, la original era:

let galletaValor = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)2023BURA07C03P07\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/,"$1",);

alert(galletaValor)

Pero quiero hacerlo con cualquier string que cargue en una variable.